# Central Java Webstart Cache

Tags: java, java-web-start

Are there any recommendations or best-use-cases how to manage the java webstart cache destination?

With the property "deployment.user.cachedir" in the deployment.properties file,  it's possible to define a central cache, shared by all users.

Is Java-Webstart-Cache designed for multiple/parallel User access?

The idea was to have one central Java Webstart Cache for all systems and users 
in our Citrix Environment. Is this a good idea?

Greetings

Comment: Note that if an app. stores user preferences in a sub-directory of user home, the users will all share those preferences.

Comment: "users will all share those preferences": I don't think this statement is true because preferences are saved in HKEY_CUREENT_USER registry. So even if the app executables are shared, their preferences will be stored in different registry per user account.